# Is the Korean alphabet to English charts the pronunciation or the actual meaning in English?

Tags: hangul

I’m a relatively confused Korean student who is very interested in learning but I have hit a wall. I understand the forming of a word using blocks/the structure, but the “alphabet” charts are confusing me.

For example: 
[image: Example of what I mean]

Are those English translations or pronunciations? Does “ㅏ” quite literally mean “A” or is that how it’s pronounced?

Comment: I'm confused on how we're supposed to pronounce o. Would it be oh, because that's what another letter is.

Answer (score 2):

This chart is for Korean vowels

In Korean a full sound is made by combining a consonant (자음) with a vowel (모음)

The chart in the question shows the pronunciation of the vowel sounds, but since the vowel characters are not used by themselves, their pronunciation is also the word used to refer to them

For example, the sound Ga is formed by the vowel ㄱ followed by the consonant ㅏ(ah) to give Ga (가)

Note that most Korean sounds do not have an exact English equivalent, so although ㅏ has been transliterated into English as 'ah', the 'h' at the end is not pronounced. The pronunciation is more like 'aa'

Also note that the consonants, on the other hand hand, [each have their own name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_consonant_and_vowel_tables#Consonant_letters'_names)